# Repetitive occurrence of employees error by month

Tags: sas

I have a three columns

Sample data:

```
Employee_ID   Error_Type     Month    Count
-------------------------------------------
     101.        A.          Jan'21     1
     102.        B.          Jan'21     1
     103.        C.          Jan'21     1

     101         B.          Feb'21     1
     102.        B.          Feb'21     2
     103.        C.          Feb'21     2

     101.        A.          Mar'21     1
     102.        B.          Mar'21     3
     103.        A.          Mar'21     1

     101.        A.          Apr'21     2

     102.        B.          May'21     3
     103.        C.          May'21     2
```

I need to calculate last column which is Count in SAS

Example:

1. If employee made same error in Jan'21, Feb'21, Mar'21 then count is 3.
2. If employee made same error in Jan'21 Feb'21, May'21 then count is 2 because repetitive months are Jan'21 and Feb'21 so same count has to be marked for May'21

Please drop your comment. THANKS

Comment: Why is Count = 3 for Employee_ID = 102 in May21? Seems to me, he made the same error 4 times?

Comment: Also, why is Count = 2 for Employee_ID = 103 in May21? The Error_Type changed since Mar21?

Answer (score 0):

```
data have;
input Employee_ID Error_Type $ Month : monyy5.;
format Month monyy5.;
datalines;
101 A Jan21
102 B Jan21
103 C Jan21
101 B Feb21
102 B Feb21
103 C Feb21
101 A Mar21
102 B Mar21
103 A Mar21
101 A Apr21
102 B May21
103 C May21
;   

data want(drop = e);
   if _N_ = 1 then do;
      dcl hash h();
      h.definekey("Employee_ID");
      h.definedata("e", "m", "Count");
      h.definedone();
   end;
   
   set have;
   
   if h.find() then Count = 1;
   
   else do;
      if e  = Error_Type and intck("month", m, Month) = 1 then Count + 1;
      if e ne Error_Type and intck("month", m, Month) = 1 then Count = 1;
   end;
   
   e = Error_Type;
   m = Month;
   
   h.replace();
run;
```